# To remove only junk characters from a text file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file which contains folder and file names with junk characters inserted in between. I want to filter only folder names, below is an example:

```
/TEST/C/Users/Account/Documents/T/Java/Reach/con/trail-and-error/modify/web/jk/args-pasre/library/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/key-check-folat.js
```

I want my output to be:

```
/TEST/C/Users/Account/Documents/T/Java/Reach/con/trail-and-error/modify/web/jk/args-pasre/library/key-check-folat.js
```

Tried doing below, but it removes "/" and "-" characters from list.

```
echo "/TEST/C/Users/Account/Documents/T/Java/Reach/con/trail-and-error/modify/web/jk/args-pasre/library/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/key-check-folat.js" | tr -cd '[:alnum:]'
```

Comment: What do you mean *junk*?

Comment: °/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/ these characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ echo "/TEST/C/Users/Account/Documents/T/Java/Reach/con/trail-and-error/modify/web/jk/args-pasre/library/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/°/key-check-folat.js" | sed 's/\/°//g'
/TEST/C/Users/Account/Documents/T/Java/Reach/con/trail-and-error/modify/web/jk/args-pasre/library/key-check-folat.js
```

Comment: Probably better with something like `sed -E 's/\/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]+//'`

Comment: Yes, if he would have specified that he wants to remove all non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Agreed, the "junk" characters reference is ambiguous and you handle the example he gave just fine.